# I want to access my Django project which i am running from Red Hat machine

Tags: django, ip, redhat

The Development server gets started on he System's IP.

```
[Yash@Yash qpcm]$ python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.57:8000
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4, using settings 'qpcm.settings'
Development server is running at http://192.168.1.57:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I can access this ip address from the same system, but this ip is inaccessible from the other systems connected through same wifi and Lan. The other systems are ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.57` is a *private* IP. Instead, you need to bind the server to an external IP with something like `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: Hey mevius, i am testing my app locally by wifi by which many systems are connected. I was able to connect system when i wrote the same command in windows or ubuntu, but in Redhat its not working. Is there some other solution for it?